# Using an autofilter with a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, autofilter

I'm trying to apply a filter to multiple workbooks in a folder. The loop in my code works to open all the `.xlsm` files in a given folder, but I am having trouble applying a loop to the filter. I need the same filter to apply to all workbooks.

I hope I'm really close to getting this and it's just something simple I'm missing here.

The first, longer macro opens all `.xlsm` files in a given folder, but only autofilters the active workbook, not all of the opened books. The second macro is my attempt to simplify the macro, but without any success except that the file dialog box opens and I can select the folder, but nothing after that happens. No files open or are filtered.

On that macro, I'm getting

> Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

on the `.autofilter field:=1....`

```
Sub Main()

    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsm")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open xStrPath & "\" & xFile
        xFile = Dir
    Loop

'Filter_Rows_By_RSSID

    For Each xWB In Application.Workbooks
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("5649", "15899", "16583", "27314", "27471", "32551", "33111", "33124", "34404", "34607", "35157", "35331", "35546", "57203", "57450", "57803", "58119", "58413"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

    Next

End Sub

Sub BadLoopThroughFiles()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("5649", "15899", "16583", "27314", "27471", "32551", "33111", "33124", "34404", "34607", "35157", "35331", "35546", "57203", "57450", "57803", "58119", "58413"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
           xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In the first Sub, `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` always referes to the Active Workbook.  Try `With xWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` instead.

Comment: Also, remove `On Error Resume Next` . It may be hiding other issues from you.

Comment: Thank you! This works great! The only thing that changes now is that it doesn't filter that sheet I execute it from. Fixing one sheet is MUCH better than the 100+ of these I'll be doing so though!

Comment: One other question though since this fix worked. You said that With Worksheets only refers to the active workbook. What is xWB. referring to/how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Your `With` block

```
With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("5649", "15899", "16583", "27314", "27471", "32551", "33111", "33124", "34404", "34607", "35157", "35331", "35546", "57203", "57450", "57803", "58119", "58413"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
```

Will cause this error because you're neither specifying a worksheet nor a range for your autofilter.

You could set a variable = the workbook you're opening and reference the worksheet & range to autofilter. Then you can delete the `With` block, since you're only using it for that.

```
Dim wb as Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("5649", "15899", "16583", "27314", "27471", "32551", "33111", "33124", "34404", "34607", "35157", "35331", "35546", "57203", "57450", "57803", "58119", "58413"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: `xFdItem` is the path to the folder you have selected from the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` in `xFd`.